# How do you dynamically create a class with a given method and method body in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, metaprogramming

In Ruby how would you **define a method**

`def make_class(method_name, method_body, s_value)`

**returning a class** with the following implementation

```
class Anonymous
    def method_name(args)
        method_body(args)
    end

    def to_s
       return s_value
    end
end
```

If you can link to any resources you found useful on basic Ruby metaprogramming that would be great as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use smth like that:

```
def make_class(s_value, method_name, &method_body)    
  Class.new do   
    define_method method_name, method_body    

    define_method :to_s do    
      s_value    
    end    
  end
end    

klass = make_class 'foo instance', :foo do |*args|    
  "called foo with #{args.inspect}"    
end    

k = klass.new     
puts k.to_s                 # => foo instance
puts k.foo [1, 2], 'hello'  # => called foo with [[1, 2], "hello"]
```

In that case you are supposed to pass your method's body as a block (you can replace `|*args|` with any list of arguments you want to have as parameters for you method). If you want to pass `method_body` not as a block but as a string then `eval` is your friend.

Comment: Just ran this snippet, it works.  Metaprogramming doesn't seem so tricky after all.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
def make_class(method_name, method_body, s_value)
  Class.new {
    define_method method_name do |*args|
      eval(method_body)
    end

    define_method :to_s do
      s_value
    end
  }
end
```

["Metaprogramming Ruby: Program Like the Ruby Pros"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476) is a very good book to learn about ruby metaprogramming.

Comment: Thanks for the book, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I can think of:

```
def make_class(method_name, method_body, s_value)
  klass = Class.new
  klass.class_eval "def #{method_name} ; #{method_body} ; end"
  klass.class_eval "def to_s ; #{s_value} ; end"
  klass
end
```

Usage:

```
>> Anonymous = make_class(:foobar, "puts 'foo'", 23)
=> Anonymous
>> a = Anonymous.new
=> 23
>> a.foobar
foo
=> nil
>> a.to_s
=> 23
```

Edit: ok, I was a bit too simplistic here, this doesn't handle the args for the method.

Answer (score 0):

i would not recommend doing this, but you could...

```
def make_class(method_name, method_body, s_value)
  eval("
  class Anonymous
      def #{method_name}(args)
          #{method_body}(args)
      end

      def to_s
         return '#{s_value}'
      end
  end
  ")
end

make_class(:bla, :puts, 'bla')
Anonymous.new.bla('moin')
puts Anonymous.new.to_s
```

returning

```
moin
bla
```